# Wordpress : custom menu, add class "current-menu-item" on <a> tags

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, menu

I use a CSS framework and a custom menu for wordpress :

```
<?php
        $menuParameters = array(
            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
            'menu_id' => 'primary-menu',
            'container'       => false,
            'echo'            => false,
            'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
            'depth'           => 0,
        );

        $output = strip_tags(wp_nav_menu($menuParameters),'<a>');
        $output = preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="nav-item"', $output);
        echo $output;       
        ?>
```

Result :

```
    <div class="nav-right nav-menu">
<a class="nav-item" href="/">Page1</a>
<a class="nav-item" href="/"> Page2</a>
<a class="nav-item" href="/"> Page3</a>
    </div>
```

And what I want : (If I'm on the page "Page 2")

```
    <div class="nav-right nav-menu">
<a class="nav-item" href="/">Page1</a>
<a class="nav-item current-menu-item" href="/"> Page2</a>
<a class="nav-item" href="/"> Page3</a>
    </div>
```

I don't find hook, walker_menu, or an other solution to add a class on the current menu (like "current-menu-item on the original Wordpress menu)

Any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Could you post the result you want? Have you checked [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)

Comment: I edit my post to add the result I want. I I've already checked that yes, thank you, but I don't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to use a different class when active? You could use `:active`

see: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Then your CSS would be like:

```
.nav-item :active{ background:yellow;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the below

Add to your `$menuParameters` the `current` arg.

```
 $menuParameters = array(
            'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
            'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            'container'      => false,
            'current'        => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ), // added this
            'echo'           => false,
            'items_wrap'     => '%3$s',
            'depth'          => 0,
        );

    $output = strip_tags(wp_nav_menu($menuParameters),'<a>');

    $output = preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="nav-item"', $output);

    $output = preg_replace('/current', 'current-menu-item', $output); // added this

    echo $output;       
    ?>
```

If that doesn't work, play a little with the `$output`'s second `preg_replace` or remove it and just refer to the active item when it has just the class `current` and not `current-menu-item` . If you remove it, i would expect the below result :

```
<div class="nav-right nav-menu">
    <a class="nav-item" href="/">Page1</a>
    <a class="nav-item current" href="/"> Page2</a>
    <a class="nav-item" href="/"> Page3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it didn't work, even playing with $output. The menu doesn't appear at all.

Comment: Have you tried removing completely the `$output = preg_replace('/current',...` ?

Comment: Yes I tried, the menu appear, but just with the class "nav-item"

Comment: So no `<a/>` had the class `current`? Another way would be to do it qith jQuery..when page is loaded check the current paged variable and add class to the appropriate `nav-item`